# How to configuring Apache as a Reverse Proxy for a Django App in a Docker Container: Serving Static Files

Tags: django, docker, apache, django-staticfiles, static-files

I have Django app that runs in docker container. **I have a problem with serving static files with my Apache configuration.**

- My django app works inside docker container and Apache correctly routes requests to it
- I made sure to set `STATIC_URL = "/static/"` and `DEBUG = False` settings properties
- I made sure to collect static to `/var/www/my_app/static/` directory
- I made sure that directory `/var/www/my_app` has correct acccess rights for apache: `drwxr-xr-x  3 www-data www-data 4,0K June 11 16:25 my_app`

This is my apache config:

```
<VirtualHost 000.00.0.000:443>
    ServerName my_app.com

    SSLEngine on
    SSLProxyEngine on

    SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/certs/cert.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/certs/cert.key
    SSLCACertificateFile /etc/apache2/certs/DigiCertCA.crt

    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/my_app.log combined
    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/my_app.log
    
    ProxyPass /static !  
    Alias /static/ /var/www/my_app/static/

    <Directory /var/www/my_app/static/>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    <Location />
        ProxyPass http://localhost:6000/
        ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:6000/
        ProxyPreserveHost on
    </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

When I commented out:

```
<Location />
ProxyPass http://localhost:6000/
ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:6000/
ProxyPreserveHost on
</Location>
```

than my static files are served properly. So it looks like that there is some issue that the this part of the config takes precedence.

Could you help me please to resolve the issue?

Comment: Hello @przemek, if my answer is helpful for you to fix the problem, you can accept it as answer (click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in). this can be beneficial to other community members. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Apache's webserver order of precedence is pretty complicated and is documented [here](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/sections.html#merging) but explained beautifully [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/391457/how-does-apache-merge-multiple-matching-location-sections). In your case, the `ProxyPass` inside the `Location` block takes precedence as it wins the last match. Either you can arrange your configuration and place the `<Directory>` directive below your `<Location>` block, or you can create another `<Location /my_app/static/` block at the end which will help you to better evaluate which block will match what.